# Maybe you should consider

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

A guy walks up to a girl drinking at the bar and tries to make conversation, but she just ignores him, so he says:

*Maybe you should consider staying at home to drink next time if you don't want to be disturbed.*

Questions:

1) Is this phrased and structured in a natural way or could it be better?

2) If I wanted to change **next time**, which of these would work instead: **some other time** or **another time**.

Comment: The original "next time" is better, but whether or not being rude comes naturally... is another question.

Comment: No, neither ***some other time*** nor ***another time*** would be idiomatically acceptable in your context. On very rare occasions I might hear a native speaker say something like ***Another time** [please have the exact fare ready, or some other "future instruction"]*, but it's nearly always ***Next time*** in such contexts. Why would you seek alternatives?